# Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'. It will be removed at the end of 2018

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio version 3.1 dependencies compile word is replaced to implementation. dependencies with Warning in android studio 3.1:

```
dependencies { 
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0' 
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
//            shrinkResources true
//            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

comment `shrinkResources true` and `minifyEnabled true` it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you have to replace `compile` with `implementation` in dependencies since `compile` is obsolete.

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49929306/5322970) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because since Gradle 3.4 (Android Studio 3.1 is using Gradle >= 4.6) is [introducing new configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations):

> Gradle 3.4 introduced new Java Library plugin configurations that
>   allow you to control whether a dependency is published to the compile
>   and runtime classpaths of projects that consume that library. The
>   Android plugin is adopting these new dependency configurations, and
>   migrating large projects to use them can drastically reduce build
>   times. The following table helps you understand which configurations
>   you should use.

As the warning says, the `compile` configuration will be removed from gradle at the end of 2018.

Answer (score 0):

replace all the 'compile's with 'implementation' in the (Module:app)
 (in your code it looks like this ) :

`implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0' 
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`