# Android Studio building errors using react native app

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, react-native, android-studio-3.1

I have been trying to create an app using react native using expo tools xde and then detach it using exp detach, when I open in Android Studio I get quite many error when building like:

```
Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018.
For more information see:
http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html


The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored,
as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android
Gradle Plugin 3.1.1. Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used. To
suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your
build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now
has a default version of the build tools. Update Build Tools version
and sync project Open File


Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018.
For more information see:
http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html


Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
'testImplementation' and 'testApi'. It will be removed at the end of
2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html


Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with
'testImplementation'.
```

Is this normal? you could ask me why did you detach, well for that I have reasons.

How can create a detach app in react native and have a bit smoother experience when it comes to compiling building the app in android studio?

ps: I am using Android Studio 3.1.1 and I somehow seem to be using latest version of Gradle [https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip][1], idk if this comes from the prespective of the react app or I have somehow updated thru Android studio.

Also I do not seem to have anymore compile on my dependencies in app.build.graddle and it is still complaining about it I subtstituted with implementation already

Answer (score 3):

As the error states, you have to replace `compile` with `implementation` in dependencies since compile is obsolete.

Example

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    ....
}
```

Comment: I have update the 'compile' with 'implementation' but still getting warnings.

Comment: @Habib, I updated the compile with implementation as well and I am also still getting warnings. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I resolved this, it was not android studio problem, I think it was an issue from my side. I didn't work on react-native from past 6 months so I don't remember what I did to resolve it. I wish I could help you with it.