# android gradle plugin version below 2.+ has been deprecated at end 2018 that is true?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, compiler-warnings, deprecated

In current my android project i have use android `gradle` plugin version 2.3.0 but when i try to complier i have receive this warning

> Warning:Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018

i see in [Google's Maven Repository](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) and i see at `com.android.tools.build -> gradle` i don't found index of gradle version below 2.+
[image]
Did any one know is my assumption is true? If it true how can i found reference link for this announcement from google android official web site?

Thank you.

Comment: The error warning is not about gradle plugin version , its about using `compile` in `build.gradle` file . Replace `compile` with `implementation` and every thing should work fine

Comment: Ok i got it many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you have to replace compile with implementation in dependencies since compile is obsolete.

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49812692/android-studio-building-errors-using-react-native-app/49929306#49929306) for example.